# Sketch complex function without any software

Tags: analysis, complex-numbers

[image]
I was asked for a school project to sketch this and we were advised to do it without sny software, because we must be able to sketch something like that in our exams.But I am generally interested in the question. I tried to manipulate it with euler's identity to bring into a more familiar form but I can 't see how i can sketch something like that.
I meant , **to bring into the form $a+jb$ in order to have the real - part graph and and the arg(X) part for the angle** but it did not work. Any help appreciated.

$X(\Omega) = (\frac{1}{1 - a^{-1} e^{-j\Omega}})^3 = (\frac{e^{j\Omega}}{e^{-j\Omega} - a^{-1} })^3 = (\frac{cos(\Omega) + j sin(\Omega)}{cos(\Omega) + j sin(\Omega) - a^{-1} })^3$

update* : $X(\Omega)=(\frac{cos(\Omega) + j sin(\Omega) - a^{-1} }{cos(\Omega) + j sin(\Omega)})^{-3} = (1 - a^{-1}cos(\Omega)+ja^{-1}sin(\Omega))^{-3}$

I wonder:
Can I say that ? $Re{X(\Omega)} = ((1 - a^{-1}cos(\Omega))^{-3}$ and
$Im{{X(\Omega)}} = (a^{-1}sin(\Omega))^{-3}$ ?
and $|X(\omega)| = \sqrt{Re^2{X(\omega)} + Im^2{X(\Omega)} }$
and $Arg(X) = tan^{-1}(\frac{Im{X}}{Re{X}})$

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible ways to proceed.

I)
$$
\left\{ \matrix{
  1 - {1 \over a}e^{\, - j\,\Omega }  = 1 - {1 \over a}\cos \Omega  + j{1 \over a}\sin \Omega  =  \hfill \cr 
   = {1 \over a}\sqrt {\left( {a - \cos \Omega } \right)^{\,2}  + \sin ^{\,2} \Omega } \;e^{\,j\,\Phi }  =  \hfill \cr 
   = {1 \over a}\sqrt {1 + a^{\,2}  - 2a\cos \Omega } \;e^{\,j\,\Phi }  = R\,e^{\,j\,\Phi }  \hfill \cr 
  \Phi  = \arctan _{\,4} \left( {{{\sin \Omega } \over {a - \cos \Omega }}} \right) \hfill \cr}  \right.
\quad  \Rightarrow \quad \left( {1 - {1 \over a}e^{\, - j\,\Omega } } \right)^{\, - 3}
  = R^{\, - 3} e^{\, - j\,3\,\,\Phi } 
$$
where $ \arctan _{\,4}$ denotes the arctan over the four quadrants.

II)
$$
\eqalign{
  & {1 \over {1 - {1 \over a}e^{\, - j\,\Omega } }}
 = {1 \over {1 - {1 \over a}\cos \Omega  + j{1 \over a}\sin \Omega }} =   \cr 
  &  = {{1 - {1 \over a}\cos \Omega  - j{1 \over a}\sin \Omega } \over {R^{\,2} }} \cr} 
$$

from which
$$
\eqalign{
  & \left( {{1 \over {1 - {1 \over a}e^{\, - j\,\Omega } }}} \right)^{\,3}  =   \cr 
  &  = {1 \over {R^{\,6} }}\left( \matrix{
  \left( {1 - {1 \over a}\cos \Omega } \right)^{\,3} 
 - j3{1 \over a}\left( {1 - {1 \over a}\cos \Omega } \right)^{\,2} \sin \Omega  +  \hfill \cr 
   - {3 \over {a^{\,2} }}\left( {1 - {1 \over a}\cos \Omega } \right)\sin ^{\,2} \Omega 
 + j{1 \over {a^{\,3} }}\sin ^{\,3} \Omega  \hfill \cr}  \right) =   \cr 
  &  = {1 \over {a^{\,3} R^{\,6} }}\left( \matrix{
  \left( {a - \cos \Omega } \right)^{\,3}  - 3\left( {a - \cos \Omega } \right)\sin ^{\,2} \Omega  +  \hfill \cr 
   + j\left( {\sin ^{\,3} \Omega
  - j3\left( {a - \cos \Omega } \right)^{\,2} \sin \Omega } \right) \hfill \cr}  \right) =   \cr 
  &  = {1 \over {a^{\,3} R^{\,6} }}\left( \matrix{
  \left( {a - \cos \Omega } \right)\left( {\left( {a - \cos \Omega } \right)^{\,2}
  - 3\sin ^{\,2} \Omega } \right) +  \hfill \cr 
   + j\sin \Omega \left( {\sin ^{\,2} \Omega
  - 3\left( {a - \cos \Omega } \right)^{\,2} } \right) \hfill \cr}  \right) \cr} 
$$

Comment: I think we are supposed to split it into 2 graphs:  $|X(\omega)|$  and $arg(X)$, i updated my thoughts if you want to provide me with some feedback